# SQL subquery in the AND statement

Tags: sql, subquery

A couple problems.

1. **Solved** `valid_from_tsp <> max(valid_from_tsp)` - how can I get my query to filter based on not being the max date? This idea doesn't work The error being returned is: "Improper use of an aggregate function in a WHERE clause"
2. My second issue is when I run it without the date, I am returned a syntax error: `Syntax error, expected something like 'IN' keyword or 'CONTAINS' keyword between ')' and ')'`

What do you see that I don't? Thanks in advance

**Edited Query**

```
select 
   a.*, 
   b.coverage_typ_cde as stg_ctc 
from P_FAR_BI_VW.V_CLAIM_SERVICE_TYP_DIM a
   inner join (select distinct etl_partition_id, coverage_typ_cde from 
     P_FAR_STG_VW.V_CLAIM_60_POLICY_STG where row_Create_tsp > '2013-11-30 23:23:59')b 
   on (a.etl_partition_id = b.etl_partition_id)
where a.valid_from_tsp > '2013-11-30 23:23:59' 
and a.coverage_typ_cde = ' '
and (select * from P_FAR_SBXD.T_CLAIM_SERVICE_TYP_DIM where service_type_id = 136548255 
   and CAST(valid_from_tsp AS DATE) <> '2014-03-14')
```

Trouble part: `and (select * from P_FAR_SBXD.T_CLAIM_SERVICE_TYP_DIM where service_type_id = 136548255 
       and CAST(valid_from_tsp AS DATE) <> '2014-03-14')`

I am trying to filter by the date on the service_type_id, and I am getting the error in question 2

*As for sample data:* This is kinda tricky, This query returns many thousands of rows of data. Currently when I do the inner join, I get a secondary unique index violation error. So I am trying to filter out everything but the more recent which could be under that violation (service_type_id is the secondary index)

If I bring back three rows with the service_type_id with three different valid_from_tsp timestamps, I only want to keep the newest one, and in the query, not return the other two.

Comment: Perhaps you should post sample data and desired results.  A non-working query doesn't always do justice to the problem that needs to be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select a.*,  b.coverage_typ_cde as stg_ctc 
from P_FAR_BI_VW.V_CLAIM_SERVICE_TYP_DIM a inner join
     (select distinct etl_partition_id, coverage_typ_cde
      from P_FAR_STG_VW.V_CLAIM_60_POLICY_STG
      where row_Create_tsp > '2013-11-30 23:23:59'
     ) b 
     on (a.etl_partition_id = b.etl_partition_id)
where a.valid_from_tsp > '2013-11-30 23:23:59' and
      a.coverage_typ_cde = ' ' and
      (select *
       from P_FAR_SBXD.T_CLAIM_SERVICE_TYP_DIM
       where service_type_id = 136548255 and
             CAST(valid_from_tsp AS DATE) <> '2014-03-14'
      );
```

In general, you cannot have a subquery just there in the `where` clause with no condition.  Some databases might allow a scalar subquery in this context (one that returns one row and one column), but this isn't a scalar subquery.  You can fix the syntax by using `exists`:

```
where a.valid_from_tsp > '2013-11-30 23:23:59' and
      a.coverage_typ_cde = ' ' and
      exists (select 1
              from P_FAR_SBXD.T_CLAIM_SERVICE_TYP_DIM
              where service_type_id = 136548255 and
                    CAST(valid_from_tsp AS DATE) <> '2014-03-14'
             );
```

Comment: I was looking at it a little closer and noticed I didn't have a condition.  Thank you for the fix!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about your second question, but your first error is due to using an aggregate function `max` in a where clause. I'm not really sure what you want to do here, but a quick fix is to replace `max(valid_from_tsp)` with a subquery that only returns the maximum value.